# Getting Next Record between two dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes:

```
DataFrame 1:
ID
3000
4000
5000
6000

DataFrame2:
ID     Value
3000    1
3010    2
3020    3
4010    4
5000    5
6000    6 
7000    7
```

I need to join both frames on ID where Dataframe1.ID < (top 1 in dataframe2, but in 1000 increments).

The result would be

```
Dataframe1       Dataframe2.ID       value
3000               4010                4
4000               5000                5
5000               6000                6
6000               7000                7
```

The way i did it in sql server is joined to ID in (which was divided by 1000 and rounded to nearest number)  then i got the top 1 greatest number from dataframe2.  I'm not sure how to do this in R..

where dataframe1.ID/1000 < (select top 1 dataframe2.ID/1000 order by dataframe2.ID)   I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing this in R.

Comment: Should value be `4,5,6,7` in the output instead? `4010` ID has a Value of `4` in DF2

Comment: yes, sorry about that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using data.table

**Code**

```
df1[, DF2ID := lapply(ID, function(x){
  ind = nrow(df2) + 1 - sum(x + 1000 <= df2[, ID])
  return(df2[ind, ID])
})]

df1[, value := sapply(DF2ID, function(x){
  df2[which(ID == x), Value]
})]
```

**Result**

```
> df1
     ID DF2ID value
1: 3000  4010     4
2: 4000  5000     5
3: 5000  6000     6
4: 6000  7000     7
```

**Data**

```
df1 = data.table(ID = seq(3000, 6000, 1000))
df2 = data.table(ID = c(3000, 3010, 3020, 4010, 5000, 6000, 7000),
                 Value = seq(1:7))
```

I am assuming that Jonny Phelp's comment regarding `value` is correct. Otherwise, this is easily mended in the second line of code. Furthermore, there surely exists a more elegant way of simply retrieving `ind` from the first lapply statement in order to produce `value`.

**Edit: The following procedure is perhaps more elegant:**

```
df1 = data.table(ID_df1 = seq(3000, 6000, 1000))
df2 = data.table(ID_df2 = c(3000, 3010, 3020, 4010, 5000, 6000, 7000),
                 Value = seq(1:7))


df1[, Value := sapply(ID_df1, function(x){
  nrow(df2) + 1 - sum(x + 1000 <= df2[, ID_df2])
})]

df_master = merge(df1, df2, by = 'Value')

> df_master
   Value ID_df1 ID_df2
1:     4   3000   4010
2:     5   4000   5000
3:     6   5000   6000
4:     7   6000   7000
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!! im still trying to learn R, can you explain function part is doing?

Comment: Sure thing, will do once time allows!

Comment: how can i get the whole data set?  i tried this finalResult<-df1[, value := sapply(DF2ID, function(x){
  df2[which(ID == x), Value]
})]   but i get an error  Output data 'finalResult$DF2ID' has illegal type: 'list''.  I can't merge by value because the value could be the same

Comment: Let me explain what my bottom example does, as I think it is the easiest to comprehend. The code finds the `Value` in df2 corresponding to each `ID_df1`. Example: for `ID_df1 == 3000`,  the appropriate `ID_df2` equals `4010`, and the corresponding Value is 4. Hence, for `ID_df1 == 3000`, `Value = 4`. Once we have the appropriate `Value` in df1, we simply merge the two tables on `Value`. Regarding your problem, did you convert your dataframes to data.tables?